# RestKit + Swift Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, restkit

I have a Framework project that is responsible for communicating with Restfull services. I'm using RestKit and the project compiles and runs without errors but no call is made on the server and nothing appears in the logs

```
    RKLogConfigureFromEnvironment()

    let estrategiaMapping: RKObjectMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: EstrategiaDTO.self)
    estrategiaMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromArray(["id", "nome", "grp"])

    let statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClass.Successful);

    //let requestDesc = RKRequestDescriptor(mapping: estrategiaMapping, objectClass: EstrategiaDTO.self, rootKeyPath: "", method: RKRequestMethod.GET)

    let responseDesc = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: estrategiaMapping, method: RKRequestMethod.GET, pathPattern: "/estrategias/:id", keyPath: nil, statusCodes: statusCodes)

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000")
    let restserver = RKObjectManager(baseURL: url)

    restserver.addResponseDescriptor(responseDesc)
    //restserver.addRequestDescriptor(requestDesc)

    RKObjectManager.sharedManager().getObjectsAtPath("/estrategias/5", parameters: nil, success: { (operation, result) -> Void in
        println(result)
        }) { (operation, error) -> Void in
            println(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

**UPDATE 1**

I have created a new project and configure RestKit successfully. I believe it was something wrong in the installation and configuration process. But now we are good to go!

The idea is to separate the data access layer (Restfull services) in a framework that can be plugged into projects that need to consume these REST services.

MyNormal-iOSApp -> MyDataApi-Framework -> RestKit

When I import the framework "MyDataApi" into the "MyNormal-iOSApp" an error occurs stating that the import of RestKit has not been resolved within MyDataApi-Framework.

MyDataApi-Framework compiles gracefully. But the above error occurs when used from within "MyNormal-iOSApp".

How to make this work?

Comment: What debugging have you done? How are you testing? What code should be triggering the request?